# Strange sharpening effect in B/W negative scan

Tags: film, black-and-white, scanning, sharpening

I am scanning several rolls of B/W film and have noticed that a small number of shots have some sort of strange sharpening/edge detection behaviour which looks awful. The example below is from Ilford HP5 pushed 2 stops to iso 1600, scanned with an Epson V550 scanner, shown at 100%.

Settings are: B&W negative film, 16bit grayscale, 4800 dpi, unsharp mask set to medium (default), digital ICE on.

Note that this occurs on 1-2 shots per roll - most of the shots look great. I have tried adjusting/disabling the sharpness setting but the effect remains. What is causing this? Sharpening of a relatively large amount of grain at a relatively high resolution?

[image: 100% crop from scan]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by having Digital ICE turned on for B&W photos. See example [here](https://www.lomography.com/magazine/129990-using-digital-ice-on-black-and-white-film-photos).

It's worth noting that the preview must be made again if the Digital ICE checkbox is changed.

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question - it was a genuine case of Murphy's law that I found the answer just after posting the question.

Comment: Answering your own question is absolutely fine! No need to apologize.

Comment: I've also caught myself getting frustrated because I changed a setting when scanning prints, negatives, or slides and forgot to rescan to get a fresh preview.